# Getting error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlElement"

Tags: java, selenium, testing, htmlunit-driver

I am using selenium webdriver for the testing I have written code:

```js
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.MarionetteDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
//import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class sample_google
{

 WebDriver driver;


    @BeforeTest

    public  void setUp(){

       // FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
     //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\ashwini\\geckodriver.exe");
     
//    driver= new MarionetteDriver();
      driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }


    @Test

    public void testLoadingFirstPage() throws Exception{

        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        searchBox.sendKeys("fast cars");
        searchBox.submit();
        System.out.println("Page title : " + driver.getTitle());
        WebElement resultCount = driver.findElement(By.id("resultStats"));
        System.out.println("Result Count : " + resultCount.getText());
       

    }
    @AfterTest
   public void teardown()
   {
    //driver.quit();
   }

    
}
```

However I am getting output

```js
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setUp
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlElement
 at sample_google.setUp(sample_google.java:31)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
 at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:656)
 at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
 at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
 at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
 at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
 at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 23 more

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest teardown
SKIPPED: testLoadingFirstPage

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@2752f6e2: 142 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 28 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@6e8dacdf: 14 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@2d209079: 48 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@43a25848: 15 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@b684286: 9 ms
```

I have included the jar of selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.46.0.jar in the code.
Still getting the error.
So please check what is the issue.

Thanks in advance

I have included the jar of selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.46.0.jar separately in the libraries. still getting the error

Comment: How do you run this code?

Comment: yes I have run the code and then I got this error

Comment: @Ashwini.J Are you running the code from Eclipse, IDEA etc? Or are you using the command line?

Comment: running the code from eclipse by runs as->testng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below dependency to your pom.xml file and it should work fine

```
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
<version>2.20</version>
</dependency>
```

Since 2.53 this is no longer shipped with webdriver

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Selenium main distribution package version 2.53 or later then you should add HtmlUnitDriver separately, it's no longer bundled with the standalone jar file.

If you are using Selenium 2.52 or earlier you don't need to download and install HtmlUnitDriver, it is already there.

Please make the changes accordingly, it should work fine. [Learn more.](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver)